# Hazelcast map: using equals for Map keys

Tags: dictionary, hazelcast

I'm using Hazelcast 2.6.
I have a map where the keys are Objects.

As I can read from the Hazelcast documentation http://hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html

"This class is not a general-purpose ConcurrentMap implementation! While this class implements the Map interface, it intentionally violates Map's general contract, which mandates the use of the equals method when comparing objects. Instead of the equals method this implementation compares the serialized byte version of the objects."

There is a way to force Hazelcast using equals instead of the serialized byte version of the objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer:

In Hazelcast you can't rely on the equals/hashcode defined for the key object.
You have to use objects that contains just the attributes that makes it unique.

From here: http://hazelcast.org/mastering-hazelcast/chapter-5/#hashcode-and-equals

> In most cases you probably will make use of some basic type like a
>   Long, Integer or String as key. But in some cases you will need to
>   create custom keys. But to do it correctly in Hazelcast, you need to
>   understand how this mechanism [which mechanism?] works because it
>   works differently compared to traditional map implementations. When
>   you store a key/value in a Hazelcast map, instead of storing the
>   Object, the object are serialized to byte arrays and these are stored.
>   To use the hash/equals in Hazelcast you need to know the following
>   rules:
>
> for keys: the hash/equals is determined based on the content of the
>   byte array, so equal keys need to result in equal byte arrays. See
>   [serialization chapter; serializable for warning].
>
> for values: the hash/equals is determined based on the
>   in-memory-format; for BINARY the binary format is used. For OBJECT and
>   CACHED the equals of the object is used.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your equals implementation, you can try the setting the in-memory format for the map to be "Object".  The data will then be stored in deserialized form.

Comment: As you can read here  http://hazelcast.org/mastering-hazelcast/chapter-5/#hashcode-and-equals using "Object" in the in-memory-format will use in the deserialized form for the objects in values, not the keys.